# 1 AngularJS Web App with Multiple GTM Accounts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-tag-manager

I have a single page angularjs application that acts as a portal for multiple stakeholders.

For example:

```
www.example.com/stakeholder/001/index
    www.example.com/stakeholder/001/a/b
```

and

```
 www.example.com/stakeholder/002/index.html
        www.example.com/stakeholder/002/x/y
```

They each want their own Google Tag Manager (GTM) account, so each with a different unique GTM ID. Is this possible? Currently I have one index.html, and in the **HEAD** I have specified (where UNIQUE is my GTM ID):

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-UNIQUE" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-UNIQUE');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Is it possible to dynamically swap in a GTM-ID to the above snippet, inside index.html, from, for example, a properties file?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that you could do this using GTM.

That is, you put GTM as a custom tag inside GTM, but deploy it with the GTM-UNIQUE of your choice.

Although at that point it's more like GGTMM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @J Brazier. However I have no idea what you mean. 'Put GTM as a custom tag inside GTM'? .. 'it's more like GGTMM'??? I think I know less about this stuff than you give me credit.

Comment: @HellishHeat My suggestion is that you add a single Google Tag Manager container to the page, and in this container you add a custom tag. That tag is the code for a different Google Tag Manager container, with a custom variable in place of the GTM-UNIQUE. In this manner, you can add the container of your choice to each site.
It was just a thought; in reality you would probably do better to use a simpler solution.